# How to convert message to (copco) open protocol based on tcp/ip with Java sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, protocols

I am trying to develop software for  torque. I connect to device by java sockets, but I don't know how to establish session with torque. 
Establish communication steps:

me(client):send- MID 0001

torque(server):send- MID 0002

To do this I have to convert message MID 0001 to OPEN Protocol, according to documentation the result is:002000010000000000000
When I send this message server don't answer.
Maybe my message isn't converted to Open protocol good?

[image]
[image]

I was trying with sending message as bytes or string. 
Anyone know how to establish connection with Stanley torque using alpha open protocol and Java?

My client code:

```
     public class MyClientSocket {
        private static Socket socket;

        public static void main(String args[]) {


            try {
                String host = "192.168.1.15";
                int port = 4545;
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                socket = new Socket(address, port);

                //Send the message to the server
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                String sendMessage = "002000010000000000000";

                byte[] bytes = sendMessage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);


                os.write(bytes);
//              os.writeUTF(sendMessage);

                System.out.println("Message sent to the server : " + sendMessage);

                //Get the return message from the server
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String message = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Message received from the server : " + message);


            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

this is output:

```
    Message sent to the server : 002000010000000000000
Message received from the server : null

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by myself. The last zero in message is end message zero and i had to wrote message like this:

```
"00200001000000000000\0"
```